# getting a meaningful exception with Python Retry

Tags: python, session, python-requests

Making a request to an API and I want to retry if I get 500. Alright, simple, I just use [this solution](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-practice-with-retries-with-requests) (that you can also find on SO) which works wonders:

Create this function in the beginning:

```python
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter Retry


def requests_retry_session(
    retries=3,
    backoff_factor=0.3,
    status_forcelist=(500, 502, 504),
    session=None,
):
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session
```

And later use it like so:

```python
s = requests_retry_session()

response = s.get('http://httpbin.org')
```

I also like to use this method because the main part of my code is **clear of try-catches** and readability is important to me.
This method works and retries when a request fails for the number of retries you set.

When testing the solution on an error code response: http://httpbin.org/status/500 (url that gives you status 500 response)
I get this exception:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 878, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 878, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 878, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 868, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(method, url, response=response, _pool=self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /status/500 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses'))
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Downloads/request_retry.py", line 25, in <module>
    r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/status/500')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 556, in send
    raise RetryError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.RetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /status/500 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses'))
```

My expectation was to get the exception you would get if you ran this code:

```python
import requests

response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/status/500')
response.raise_for_status()
```

(Since making a normal get request doesn't raise an exception I would use `response.raise_for_status()` to raise the expected exception.)

Doing that you'll get this small and very nice exception (which I'm looking for):

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR for url: http://httpbin.org/status/500
```

Could someone help me make sense out of these exceptions and get normal ones?

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided as the working-solution itself provides an explanation for this. You are getting a `MaxRetryError`, which in fact comes `(Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses'))`.

As it shows, you still need to catch the exception and handle it as you wish:

```
try:
    response = requests_retry_session().get(
        'http://httpbin.org/status/500',
    )
except Exception as x:
    print('It failed :(', x.__class__.__name__) # here comes your code
else:
    print('It eventually worked', response.status_code)
```

Comment: Yeah I saw this but I don't want try-catch blocks all over my code